# Changing parameters has no effect on my jQuery slider, where have I gone wrong?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

I've been messing around with [Nivo Slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/#usage) but I think I've slipped up somewhere. When trying to change the vaue for the 'controlNav' parameter, I realised that none of the parameters were working. [Here](http://jakep.info/tests/nivo/) is the slider in action. If it was working, then the buttons at the bottom would not appear, as I have set the parameter 'controlNav' to 'false'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing nivoSlider twice on the same div. Remove the first call, and the control nav will disappear.